# Create paypal form which handles both recurring and one off payments

Tags: paypal, donations

Wanted to know if paypal allowed this functionality within one form or if I have to create two separate forms in order to obtain this functionality. Currently building a donation widget for a client per their request.

If there are any documentation regarding this within paypal a link would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that no problem.  Just build your form with options for one-time or recurring payments, and then use the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) to process the checkout accordingly.

If you're working with PHP you can take a look at my [class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library), which will make the Express Checkout API calls very simple for you.

The calls you'd be utilizing are:

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) (for one-time payments)
- [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) (for subscriptions)